# Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 : jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to generate a signed bundle to update my app, and can't create it, because I receive the error msg in "Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format", apparently is looking for the file "debug.keystore" that exist where suppose to be, Any idea how to fix it, Thx in advance.

Comment: Do you find any solution?